# Create an own private network (LAN/WLAN) without NAT

Tags: wifi, dhcp

how can i set up an own private network with my RaspberryPi3 to connect my WLAN and LAN devices to? I don't want to have a router or AP. I want an own network where only the connected devices can talk to each other with no IP forwarding to the internet or so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

Comment: thank you very much. do you know what the code under chapter "Add routing and masquerade" is supposed to do ?

Comment: yes, it adds routing (which you'll need I think to get wifi<->ethernet connectivity, and masquerade ... that would be for NAT, which you wont need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install an isolated network with WLAN and wired LAN is possible but you need at least an access point (AP) and a switch for it. Because you do not want an AP it is not possible to make what you want.

**Update:**
As seen from the comment you would like to have an access point devices can connect to and talk to each other. Some access points have also some (mostly four) built-in ethernet ports to plug in an ethernet cord. If this is enough then you have an integrated device for your needs. Purchase one. If you need more ethernet ports then buy an access point with only one ethernet port and an additional switch with number of ports you need.

If you want to save the money for purchasing an access point you can do it by yourself with the Raspberry Pi. *@Jaromanda X* has given a link to a tutorial in his comment. But then you have to do with router and AP you don't want to have.

Comment: physically i want to have a rpi connected to a switch and with active wlan where connected device can talk to each other in a managed ip range e.g. 192.168.0.10 to 192.168.0.20. maybe i am not experienced enough to tell if i really don't need an AP. how would you call such a solution?

Comment: @CrimsonGhost It is a network with a switch and an access point. The "thing" that makes the active wlan where connected devices can talk to each other is an access point.

Comment: @CrimsonGhost I have updated my answer.

Comment: Tanks for your reply. I want to use a Pi for this application because i have several python scripts to test the connected devices. can i get what i want to achieve with the link posted by Jaromanda X??

Comment: @CrimsonGhost Look at my answer. If does it help you it would be nice when you can accept the answer, the tick on the left side. This would finish your question and show others that it has an answer and do not try to help for nothing.

Comment: as i said maybe i am not experienced enough to know if i really don't want a router or an AP. if i can connect devices via wlan and lan together with my raspberry then i reached my goal. it's all i wanted. so final question: is it possible to achive this with the mentioned tutorial above?

Comment: @CrimsonGhost Yes you can, as I wrote in my answer: "... you can do it by yourself with the Raspberry Pi. *@Jaromanda X* has given a link to a tutorial in his comment."